# How to substitute `fwrite` by a function that always writes to `uint8_t*`

Tags: c

I want to substitute a function that uses `fwrite`. It works like this:

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    //...
    //I want to change the call below to instead write to my own function 
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    return size;
}
```

As you read in the commend, I want to change `fwrite` to instead write to my own function `myFunctionWrite(uint8_t* data, size_t size)` but as you see, my function only accepts `uint8_t*`. Writing a conversion function for all types of `nmemb` will be troublesome. Is there some function that does everything for me? Or is it easy to convert to `uint8_t*` always?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve? Maybe show the code you've tried that doesn't work? Please also pick [tag:c] or [tag:c++] they are different languages and will give different answers

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm trying to redirect `fwrite` to my own function, but it only accepts `uint8_t*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply `size` and `nmemb`.

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    //...
    size_t written = myFunctionWrite(ptr, size * nmemb);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Suppose `write_data` writes 2 elements of 32 of size. That's 64 bits to be written. Then shouldn't I write 8 8-bit elements? That is, write `myFunctionWrite(ptr, 8)`? In your example it'd write `64` 8-bit elements

Comment: `size` is in bytes, not bits.